# Fit a M3 metal screw into a M5 hole

Tags: parts, adapter

I have a M5 threaded hole into which I need to fit a M3 screw to hold some accessory.
I'm looking for the name of the piece I need to make that fit possible.

The closest I found are these kind of adapter, but they could fall in (vibration). Second closest is "rivnuts" that would not fall, but they don't fit in the tube due to the existing threads.

Schematic hereafter:

[image]

The main requirement is that the tube cannot be damaged. (eg: drilling another hole, removing the threads from the M5 hole, etc.)

Comment: No risks associated with that setup: hole already drilled & it's to hold some cheap lightweight accessory. Also, I notice I messed up the hole's thread. Other solution would be possible using straps but are out of topic here.

Comment: I would use the M3/M5 adaptor.  If you're worried about vibration working it use then add some loctite but I think the risk is low.

Comment: Rivnuts are commonly used in this situation. Remember you can always remove the existing threads.

Comment: I think the major issue is what are you attaching? The solution depends on the weight and bending moment amongst other things

Comment: Drill the accessory to accept an M5 bolt?

Comment: @Turksarama I would definitely loctite the adaptor in (if using it). There's too much chance of driving it all the way into the frame where it would rattle horribly

Comment: @jay613 that's what I'd do. I've often modified brackets for bike lights etc. Or even make a plate that picks up off a pair of bottle cage screws, and has appropriate tapped holes in it (if it's in that position)

Comment: I would use the riv-nut (and drill the threads out of the M5 hole in the tube to make it fit), but only because I already have those riv-nuts and the tool to insert & clamp them. If I had to buy everything needed for the job from scratch then I'd probably used the adapters with some loctite.

Comment: @Turksarama: thank you for your feedback. Loctite is probably what I missed in my setup to find my peace of mind. Even if it is a comment, **I consider it as the answer I was expecting.**

Comment: @brhans: indeed, I was wrong to think that the riv-nut would fit. As i don't want to damage the tube, removing the thread is out of topic. I'll rely on adapters and loctite as your second part of your answer specify. Thanks.

Comment: @jay613: **also a valid solution.** A tad more complicated with the tool I have in hand, but it could be the solution to someone else problem. Thank you.

Comment: What is the wall thickness of this tube?  Or, can you count how many threads there are cut in the hole?

Comment: Can you please tell us more about the accessory you're fitting, and some more info about it?   Photos might be handy too.

Answer (score 3):

**OPTION 1**:  The item you're looking for is indeed a **Rivnut**

These are not unique to bikes, but the M4 and M5 size is very commonly used for holding water bottle cages in place on a a thin piece of metal like a tube, where there is not a lot of depth for many threads.

[image]

A M3 rivnut needs a 5.0mm hole.  But your existing M5 threaded hole has an ID of 4.4 to 4.5mm   The solution is to drill out the existing hole to accept the M3 rivnut.

If, later on you want to install a M5 threaded fastener, you'll have to drill out the M3 rivnut and install a M5 rivnut, which needs a larger hole anyway.

---

**OPTION 2**  If this is not suitable and you really want to change between M3 and M5 bolts, then an **Interposer** may do the job.

Start by threading a M5 bolt into the hole and confirm it sits firmly without bottoming out. Depending on the thickness of the head, you might want to thin it down.

Then remove bolt from tube, and mount in a lathe or drill press.  Put a 2.5-2.7mm hole down through the center so that it is concentric with the bore.  Chamfer the end, and tap it for the standard `M3 x0.5`

Refit interposer bolt to original hole and use loctite thread locker.  Tighten without stripping original thread, and let the loctite set up.  Finally, fit your M3 bolt and accessory.

---

**OPTION 3** Helicoil or Generic replacement thread insert.   This won't work for you because the maximum hole size for a M3 helicoil is 4.35mm and your M5 bolt is over that already.

---

**OPTION 4**  Backing block.   If you have access to the inside of this tube somehow, then it may be possible to drop a backing block inside such that it lines up with the existing hole.   Then you drill and tap into this block with a M3 tap.

Downside, its unlikely you have access unless there's an inspection hatch somewhere, or you can drop a block down the seat tube.

---

**OPTION 5**   You might be able to model a clamp and 3D print it such that it surrounds the tube while supporting your accessory

Here's a small clamp/platform I made for my toptube bag to stop it rotating.  Clamps to the top tube with two M3 bolts and nuts:

[image]

---

Any other options have already been eliminated - Any form of straps around the outside can work, but cable/zip ties and velcro and jubilee clips will all damage paint over time.

Epoxy is a bit too permanent and will damage paint.